# How to setup a one to many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

I have the following models:

```
User (id, name, network_id)
Network(id, title)
```

What kind of Rails model assoc do I need to add so that I can do:

```
@user.network.title
@network.users
```

Thanks

Answer (score 62, accepted):

so network `has_many` users and a user `belongs_to` network.

Just add a `network_id` to users table if you still haven't and also since it's a `foreign_key` is worth indexing it.

`rails generate migration AddNetworkIdToUsers`

```
class AddNetworkIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :network_id, :integer
    add_index  :users, :network_id
  end
end
```

In the network model do:

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

In the user model do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
end
```

Comment: No need for the migration, the network_id is (according to the question) already in the table

Comment: true that :). just for future readers so they know how to add the id.

Comment: Shouldn't this be  with `add_reference` nowadays?

Comment: for reference, in the original Users create_table migration, it would be one line "t.references :network, foreign_key: true"

Comment: This answer needs to be updated with "add_reference".

Answer (score 9):

According to your database-setup, you just have to add the following lines to your models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
  # Rest of your code here
end

class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  # Rest of your code here
end
```

In case you have a setup without network_id, you should go with daniels answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is my way: 
run:

```
$rails generate migration AddNetworkIdToUsers
```

then config migration file:

```
class AddNetworkIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]

  def up

    add_column :users, :network_id, :integer
    add_index  :users, :network_id
  end

  def down

    remove_index :users, :network_id
    remove_column :users, :network_id
  end

end
```